I need to add multiple images for each description
I am working on mvc. I want to add multiple images for each description. I have a view page where you can add images and their respective description. However, I am not able to add multiple images in one textbox made for the image. I can select multiple images, but they are not showing in the database. I have made a button that will add more textboxes for adding new descriptions and images.
I tried to make it work with the for loop in the AddDescription action result. I want to add multiple images for each description.
public ActionResult AddDescription(List<string> Descriptions, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ImageFiles, int id)
{
    if (Descriptions == null || ImageFiles == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Descriptions or ImageFiles are missing.");
        return View();
    }
    var imagesList = ImageFiles.ToList();


    for (int i = 0; i < Descriptions.Count; i++)
    {
        var description = Descriptions[i];
    
        
        var images = ImageFiles.ToList();

      
        var imageNames = new List<string>();

        if (imagesList != null && imagesList.Any())
        {
            foreach (var image in imagesList)
            {
                if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = bll.SaveImage(image); 
                    imageNames.Add(fileName);
                }
            }   
        }

       
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) && imageNames.Count > 0)
        {
            var model = new AddStoryDTO
            {
                Description = description,
                Imagename = string.Join(",", imageNames),  
                StoryID = id
            };

            bll.AddDescription(model, id);  
        }
    }



you can try this..
The ImageFiles parameter is changed to a List<IEnumerable>, where each IEnumerable corresponds to the images related to a specific description.
public ActionResult AddDescription(List<string> Descriptions, List<IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>> ImageFiles, int id)

{
if (Descriptions == null || ImageFiles == null || Descriptions.Count != ImageFiles.Count)
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Descriptions or ImageFiles are missing or not matching.");
return View();
}
for (int i = 0; i < Descriptions.Count; i++)
{
    var description = Descriptions[i];
    var imageFilesForThisDescription = ImageFiles[i].ToList(); // Get images related to this description
    var imageNames = new List<string>();

    if (imageFilesForThisDescription != null && imageFilesForThisDescription.Any())
    {
        foreach (var image in imageFilesForThisDescription)
        {
            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = bll.SaveImage(image); 
                imageNames.Add(fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) && imageNames.Count > 0)
    {
        var model = new AddStoryDTO
        {
            Description = description,
            Imagename = string.Join(",", imageNames),
            StoryID = id
        };

        bll.AddDescription(model, id);  
    }
}

}
